# '97 Ford Ranger creeps forward while clutch pedal pressed down

Tags: ford, clutch, clutch-cylinder

I've got a '97 Ford Ranger 2.3L 2WD manual transmission.

While my car is in gear and I push the clutch pedal down, there is still a little power going to the wheels. When I'm sitting at a red light, it still wants to move forward. In higher gears, I have to match the RPM's so it will engage.  It feels like my clutch isn't disengaging all the way.

What could cause this?  How would I diagnose this?

Comment: Welcome to mechanics.SE!  Sounds like you could have air in your clutch fluid.

Comment: You could check out https://www.howacarworks.com/transmission/how-to-bleed-a-clutch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same problem once. You have to bleed your clutch as soon as possible, because you're putting a lot of wear on your gearbox' synchro rings when shifting while your clutch isn't fully disengaged. I guess you have felt that shifting may go a lot rougher than before.

Also, for now, put the box asap in neutral instead of just pushing the clutch. You minimize unduly wear on your clutch plate this way until you have bled out the clutch.

Comment: Thank you for the info, my clutch works great now. There wasn't any fluid in the reservoir and I think I had a lot of air in the lines. Can you adjust where the clutch disengages? Right now it disengages when the pedal is halfway to the floor.?Do I just remove some fluid?

Comment: Sometimes you can adjust the clutch, but not always. My car doesn't allow it. Some googling on your car about about clutch adjusting should give you the needed information if it's possible and how. Removing fluid will not change anything, and is in fact not possible without bringing air into the system and you don't want that. Gives a spongy feeling on the clutch. It's also possible there's still a bit of air in your system, but that shouldn't advance clutch disengaging, but the opposite.

Comment: By the way, no fluid in the reservoir where there first was fluid, seems like leakage to me. In other words, keep an eye on your clutch fluid level cause it might drop again and you don't want the same problem again.